# How to open a html file which is in a hidden folder?

Tags: chrome-for-android, html, folder-organizer

I have a folder which has many html files and images. I set the folder to ".myfolder" to hide the folder because it has so many images and they mess up my Gallery app. After set the folder to the hidden folder, the Gallery problem is solved. However, I could not open the html from Chrome even if I update the path. How I could open the file in a hidden folder?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like it might be easier to not use a hidden folder and just remove those images from the gallery. [Here's how.](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/39707/12442)

Comment: @DanHulme How to remove those images from the gallery? I have a few thousand of folders and each of them has at least an image.

Comment: The question I linked explains how?

Comment: I need to able to access those image files somehow. They are part of my offline website. That's why I need to open the html file in a hidden folder as I say in the topic. I have hidden everything already, but could not access the html file.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making the folder hidden with a dot prefix, create an empty file inside the folder with the name ".nomedia". This will prevent image/gallery apps from indexing the folder.

Answer (score 0):

It perhaps wasn't possible in earlier release of Chrome for Android since Chrome 45.0.x can easily open the HTML files from a hidden folder.

[image]